# Powershell count azure CLI result

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I am trying to achieve that my output if it is one single line it gets written away in a variable

This is what i have so far

```
az group list --query '[].{name:name}' --output table
$filter = Read-Host -Prompt "Please filter to find the correct resource group"
az group list --query "[?contains(name, '$filter')].name" --output tsv
```

what this code does is that you can filter all the resource groups and you get to see the ouptut in a TSV

What i am trying to add is that it checks if it is the only line and then write that line away (if it is one line)

Comment: why are you using cli instead of powershell if you use powershell anyway?

Comment: i Was thinking about which one i needed to use. Because for some parts of my script poweshell is the better option whil efor othr parts the CLI is the better option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using powershell, why not just use powershell?

```
$filter = Read-Host -Prompt "Please filter to find the correct resource group"
Get-AzResourceGroup | Where-Object { $_.ResourceGroupName -eq $filter }
```

Thanks for the help with changing the code!
The end result is now:

```
Connect-AzureRmAccount
(get-azurermresourcegroup).ResourceGroupName 
$filter = Read-Host -Prompt "Please filter to find the correct resource group" 
$RGName = get-azurermresourcegroup | Where-Object { $_.ResourceGroupName -match $filter } 
$RGName.resourcegroupname
```

Comment: i am getting an error (The term 'Get-AzResourceGroup' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program)  i am now trying to fix this error do you perhaps know how?

Comment: yeah, use the old name, get-azurermresourcegroup

Comment: okay now i get this error, (get-azurermresourcegroup : Run Connect-AzureRmAccount to login.) i added this line at the top of my code Connect-AzureRmAccount but it seems like it gets stuck at that part

Comment: i have no idea about your environment, but you can authenticate before running the script, if you want to authenticate in the script there are a couple of silent auth options, or `Enable-AzuemRmContextAutosave`

Comment: I do login with `az login` but for the rest of the script i dont have something similair like `Enable-AzuremRmContextAutosave`

Comment: there is a separate login process for azure powershell and az cli

Comment: I just tested it and it still doesnt work is there perhaps a possibilty this is a bash command and not powershell?

Comment: define `this`? those all are pure powershell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183174/discussion-between-brynn-and-4c74356b41).